# Cannot choose "SharePoint Web Application to host Project Web App"

Tags: project-server

I am working on a SP2010 farm. There are two working web application there and I am going to create a PWA on one of them.

However, in the create PWA form, in the dropdownbox "SharePoint Web Application to host Project Web App" I cannot choose the 1st web application. The dropdownbox only list the 2nd web application!

I have created successfully the PWA on 1st web application before and removed it. Is it cause the problem? I have even removed the Project Server Service Application and recreate. Still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can create PWA after I remove web application and recreate.